# How to remove the class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<div id="tab1" class="nav left">
<ul>
<li><a href="/magento/" class="now">Home</a></li>
......
</ul>
</div>
```

Now, i want to remove the `class="now"` or set the class value empty. If the url not on mangento, I using the following code. But the I don't know how to write the last part.

```
window.onload = function removeNow() {
    var div = document.getElementById("tab1").getElementsByTagName("a");
    if (window.location.pathname != '/magento/') {
        div.removeClass();
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: A general code maintainability tip: if you have a variable that is going to hold a reference to an _anchor_ element don't call it `div`. Further, if the variable is to hold the result of a method call that returns a list of items (`.getElementsByTagName()`, as its name suggests, can return element*S*, plural) it makes sense to give the variable a name that reflects this: `divs` rather than `div`, or in this case `anchors` or `links` or something.

Answer (score 6):

In modern browsers you can use the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) API:

```
div.classList.remove( 'now' );
```

But a problem specific to your code: You must loop in order to remove the class. So try this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < div.length; i++ ) {

    div[i].classList.remove( 'now' );

}
```

If your browser doesn't support `classList`, use this `removeClass` shim:

```
function removeClass( elem, name ) {

    var classlist = elem.className.split( /\s/ ), 
        newlist = [], 
        idx = 0;

    for ( ; idx < classlist.length; idx++ ) {
        if ( classlist[ idx ] !== name ) {
            newlist.push( classlist[ idx ] );
        }
    }

    elem.className = newlist.join(" ");

    return true;
}
```

or with [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (with which we are not required to use `classList` or `className`):

```
$('a').each(function() {

    if (window.location.pathname != '/magento/')
        $(this).removeClass();

});
```

Comment: TypeError: div.classList is undefined

Comment: @stackoverflow002 What browser are you using?

Comment: classList is still a fairly new API, and a number of older browsers do not support it, including some popular ones.  An alternative would be something like `div[i].className = div[i].className.replace(/\bnow\b/g, "");`

Comment: @David That `removeClass` edit seems overly complicated.  Would my one-liner in the previous comment not do pretty much the same thing, except for possibly leaving some extra blank spaces in the class name?

Comment: @ScottSauyet There can be multiple classes for one element; your example doesn't consider that. It removes the *entire* class list.

Comment: @David - no it removes any and all copies of "now" from the className attribute, although it's single-purpose whereas yours is more generic.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className) property:

```
div.className = '';
```

Comment: i am sorry, i tested the code in firebug,when on the another page, it doesn't remove the class,

Comment: Since [the `class` attribute value MUST NOT be empty](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#adef-class), and the `className` property reflects that value, the attribute should be removed instead – `div.removeAttribute("class")` –, after it has been ensured that there are no other class names in the value than those that should be removed.

Comment: Hmm, it's most likely not that line. Is your condition passing successfully? Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8cpsC/

Comment: @PointedEars: What part of the link shows that the attribute value can't be empty? (It very well could be there, I'm pretty tired)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker "A class name or set of class names" means one class name or more.

Comment: @PointedEars: I don't think the definition of cdata-list excludes empty strings. I also think you're taking the definition a bit too literally. If you go to the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and type an HTML document with an element with an empty class attribute it validates just fine. Also who says a "set" can't be empty?

Comment: @PointedEars: That document specifies requirements for the HTML markup, not for the live DOM.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Nice try. The W3C Validator, when in HTML 4.01 mode, cannot find a problem because the type of the `class` attribute in the DTD is `CDATA`. Many of the constraints in the Specification prose cannot be expressed by a DTD, including this one. An when the Validator operates in SGML or XML mode (HTML 4.01 mode being a subset of the former), it has only the DTD to validate against.

Comment: @ScottSauyet AISB, the value of HTML attribute properties in the document tree like `className` *reflects* the value of corresponding attributes in the document (here: `class`).

Comment: @PointedEars: The attributes properties of the document tree do not magically rebound back and change the markup.  That something cannot be expressed as legitimate HTML markup does not imply that it is somehow an illegitimate document.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Changing attribute properties changes the *document tree* which [causes a reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow). You can observe that, for example, in the “Elements” tab of the [Chromium Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/). It is not logical to deliberately create an error-prone document tree when there are viable alternatives.

Comment: @PointedEars: Yes, the document tree is changed.  Yes, this can cause a reflow; that in fact is probably the point of doing this.  But I see no reason to say that the document is _error-prone_.  Because one possible serialization of this document tree would be invalid does not imply there is something wrong with the document itself.  I'm not suggesting that there's anything wrong with your alternative.  But there is also nothing wrong with updating this attribute to have an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) returns a (possibly empty) [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), so:

```
var div = document.getElementById("tab1").getElementsByTagName("a");
```

is a collection of all the A element descendents of the element with ID "tab1" (and so 'div' is probably not a good name).

If all you want to do is remove all class values of the first such A element, then:

```
div[0].className = '';
```

will do the job. But since the NodeList might be empty, the following would be more robust:

```
if (div[0]) {
    div[0].className = '';
}
```

or perhaps

```
div[0] && div[0].className = '';
```

it depends on your coding style and maintainability requirements.