# How can I remove a class within an iframe using the onload function only and not javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

How can I remove a class within an iframe using the onload function only and not javascript and such?

My coding for the iframe is

`<iframe height="182" onload="this.height=this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;" scrolling="no" src="(html site I'm working with, same domain)" width="100%" frameborder="0"/>`

I've heard about removeClass() but not sure how to implement that into the iframe with onload. Thanks in advance

Note* the div only has a class, not an id (example class is 'd2l-action-buttons')

Comment: The `onload` attribute _is_ Javascript. I'm not sure what you're asking for here.

Comment: A way to have it within the <iframe> itself and not under <script> setups

Comment: remove class of an element inside the iframe or a class of the iframe itself?

Comment: class of an element inside the iframe

Answer (score 0):

It is the same like writing inside the script tag see here:
[Removing class from a Div in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154552/removing-class-from-a-div-in-javascript)
[Remove CSS class from element with JavaScript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery)
Just write it inside the onload attribute instead, so it will be something like:

```
<iframe height="182" onload="this.height=this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    this.contentWindow.document.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");" scrolling="no" src="(html site I'm working with, same domain)" width="100%" frameborder="0"/>
```

[Query Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing, just without the getElementById? the divs I'm trying to remove, none have Ids, just classes

Comment: Yes use this instead: .querySelector(".active"); as it is listed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16154694/20126

Comment: so instead of this.contentWindow.document.getElement...... use this.classlist.remove(classname)?

Comment: I updated the code to be as it should be per your comment.

Comment: thanks, and where it says 'active' just replace it with the actual class name? (example 'd2l-action-buttons')

Comment: Yes exactly, for sure

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 0):

you'll get ifram document by frames['your frame name'] try this.

```
<iframe height="500" name="utm"
  src="schould be same domain" onload="Inside_iFrame">
</iframe>

function Inside_iFrame(){
            console.log($(this, frames['utm']))
            var framDocument=$(this, frames['utm'])
            framDocument.find('your element').removeClass('your class')
        };
```

Comment: where does the "function Inside......." go? Just after the <iframe></iframe> or in a <script> ? I've not been grasping the <script> work, and I've been working within the 'inspect element' portion of chrome

Comment: before/after, just outside the iframe. even you can try it on console

Comment: alright, and in regards to the 'your element', there are no ids on the divs, just classes

Comment: ok then, inside the iframe from which from element you want to remove class?, if the class is being  used at one place the can find by same class you want to remove .find('your class').removeClass('your class')

Comment: Yeah, the element is within the iframe, and the div I want to remove only has a class name. Edited the original question with example class name

Comment: is there a way to directly implement that into the iframe brackets itself? like <iframe onload=document.find('your class').removeClass('your class') ?

Comment: you can use this key word like onload=this.document.find('your class').removeClass('your class'), not sure. but it shuold be inside function
like onload="function(){
this.document.find('your class').removeClass('your class');
}"